# how to get json data if the object has NUMBER

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Example : Iam trying to access "53" key in Ajax. but not sure how to get it.

```
JSON : 
    {
        "56": {
            "0": {



     $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            rates = json.56;
            //base = json.base;
            console.log(rates);
        }
    });
```

any help is appreciated.. 
Thanks !!

Comment: Use `[]` instead `json['56']`

Comment: Im getting this Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: down voters : this doesnt solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) :

```
var rates = json["56"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using brackets:

```
rates = json[56];
```

or

```
rates = json['56'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json[56] to access the value